# Probability that the Max of 2 Dice Rolls is X

Tags: probability

Say I roll 2 dice. What's the probability that the maximum of the 2 dice rolls is 2? I'm approaching this problem 2 ways, and am getting different answers. What am I doing wrong?

Let's call the maximum of both dice rolls to be B.

Approach 1:
$P(B = 2) = P(B \le 2) - P(B < 2) = (2/6)^2 - (1/6)^2 = 3/36$

Approach 2:
$P(B = 2) = P(B \ge 2) - P(B > 2) = (5/6)^2 - (4/6)^2 = 9/36$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Your first approach is correct.  By subtracting the probability of that each number is less than $2$ from the probability that each number is less than or equal to $2$, you are finding the probability that the largest number rolled is equal to $2$.

Notice that your second approach calculates the probability that the minimum of the two dice rolls is equal to $2$.  By subtracting the probability that each number is greater than $2$ from the probability that each number is at least $2$, you are finding the probability that the smallest number rolled is equal to $2$.

Comment: Hm I'm struggling to understand why Approach 1 is the max and approach 2 is the minimum. Could you try to offer some more intuition?

Comment: @MarioDiw  I edited my answer to elaborate on my initial statements.

Answer (score 1):

Your approaches cannot be both correct. The event $(B<2)$ is the complement of $(B\ge 2)$ so $P(B<2)=1-P(B\ge 2)$. But you wrote that $P(B<2)=(1/6)^2$ and $P(B\ge 2)=(5/6)^2$. Since $(1/6)^2+(5/6)^2\neq 1$, one of these probabilities is incorrect.

Actually, $(B<2)$ means that the maximum of the two dice is smaller than $2$. This is equivalent to the event that the two dice are smaller than $2$. In other words, the two dice are equal to $1$. Therefore, it is correct that $P(B<2)=(1/6)^2$. From there, $P(B\ge 2)=1-(1/6)^2\neq (1-1/6)^2$.

Similarly, $P(B\le 2)=(2/6)^2$ so $P(B=2)=(2/6)^2-(1/6)^2=3/36$, and your approach $1$ is correct.